# Member collection iteration thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a background thread that is performing an operation similar to this:

```cs
class Client
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IPAddress> Servers { get; private set; }

    void UpdateServers( List<IPAddress> servers )
    {
        // this will be called on a background thread

        this.Servers = new ReadOnlyCollection( servers );
    }
}
```

And on the main thread, a consumer may want to iterate the `Servers` property.

I know that with a `foreach`, the iteration would be thread-safe because the iterator would belong to the old instance if `UpdateServers` was called during the iteration.

With a `for` loop, iteration can be made safe with:

```cs
var serverList = client.Servers;
for ( int x = 0 ; x < serverList.Count ; ++x )
{
    DoSomething( serverList[ x ] );
    // ...
}
```

But what I'm wondering is if there is any way to guarantee that the compiler will generate (or force it to generate, if it doesn't already) the code above, if a consumer decides to iterate with:

```cs
for ( int x = 0 ; x < client.Servers.Count ; ++x )
```

Comment: I'd suggest not giving access to the servers variable, but instead have a method that receives a closure and does the iteration itself - or have a proper getter for Servers, whose name makes it clear that it should be called and stored into a variable, rather than used repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler generates the code you tell it to. There might be some optimizations to avoid loading the value of a field over and over, but you really shouldn't rely on those.

So, it is possible the compiler will generate the code that way, but it doesn't have to, so you should write your code as if it didn't.

Also, things like this can be very tricky (for example, I think you should also make the field `volatile`). The best choice is usually to use locks, unless those cause a real performance problem to you (which happens only rarely).

Comment: We live in fear of non-existent performance worries. These sorts of problems are hard. Correctness before performance. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind them locking each other out, this may be viable. It'll be a little heavy in terms of memory usage and object creation though. There's probably a cleaner way.

```
private ReadOnlyCollection<IPAddress> _servers;
public ReadOnlyCollection<IPAddress> Servers { 
    get {
        lock(_servers) {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<IPAddress>(_servers);
        }
    }

    private set {
        lock(_servers) {
            _servers = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to create `ReadOnlyCollection` that wraps another `ReadOnlyCollection`, it just adds overhead.

Comment: I figured as much. Go ahead and edit it to optimize it. My knowledge of that particular object is just fairly limited and returning within a lock seemed nonsensical.

The goal here was to give the caller the object at its time of access rather than maintain a lock on it while they iterate. It appears to be a memory vs locking performance question.

Answer (score 0):

you should use locks as the person above suggests, but you can also minimize the amount of time the lock is being held by not iterating over a reference to the list and using .ToArray instead and then iterating over that.

Comment: In Syddraf's answer, there is no iterating while holding a lock.

Comment: agreed but combining that method with a for loop as the op states there is

Comment: My concern is that a consumer may not follow our documentation. I was looking for a design that is implicitly thread-safe without requiring the consumer to jump through hoops to make sure their iteration is safe.

Comment: In that case Id make an actual get method instead of a property to try and discourage the users from using the property in an actual for loop.